# want to extend root partition with gparted

Tags: gparted

I want to extend my root partition with the unallocated one any help ?
These are the screen shots of my GParted:
1=>[image: Picture 1]
2=>[image: Picture 2]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Want to Extend root partiton Using Gparted on ubuntu14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/703641/want-to-extend-root-partiton-using-gparted-on-ubuntu14-04)

Answer (score 1):

The partition must not be in use so you will need to boot from live media containing GParted, for example [GParted Live](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) which includes the latest version of GParted (currently 0.24.0).

The linux swap partition (sda5) will need to be moved left so that the unallocated space is adjacent to the partition you wish to expand (sda10).  Then you should be able to expand the sda10 partition to the left which involves moving the partition and growing it.  Please note that you should have your Linux boot media handy in case you need to restore the ability to boot.  See the [GParted FAQ](http://gparted.org/faq.php) for more details on restoring boot.

**Before proceeding I highly recommend you make a back up of all your data in case anything goes wrong due to a power outage, hardware failure, or software bugs.**